# How do you group vertices as a section in a mesh?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, selection-tools

In edit mode, is there a quick way to designate a group of vertices/faces in the same mesh of an object? Designated in such a way that one can form a list of sections on a mesh, and simply select the specific section to quickly highlight the vertices? Like taking a whole cow and designating sections of it as the ribs, flank, etc.

Additionally, if there is such a way for designagtion, once the section is highlighted, is there a way to manipulate the vertices within the perimeter of that section, independent of the vertices outside the section's perimeter?

For example i wanted to use the move function on 'flanks' to raise the vertices within this section without moving any vertices on the 'ribs', and each section's perimeter is essentially anchored and unmoving on the mesh. Does blender support this? Is there a workaround for this process?

Comment: It sounds like vertex groups no?

Answer (score 2):

Select the vertex that you want to group and go to vertex groups.

[image]

Create a new group, you can rename it (for example 'flanks'). Then click assign.

[image]

Now every time that you click on select (on edit mode) Blender will automatically select your vertex.